# Ksoap2 2.5.4 and HttpsTransportSE vs AndroidHttpTransport

Tags: android, ksoap2

This works fine but AndroidHttpTransport is deprecated:

```
AndroidHttpTransport t = new AndroidHttpTransport("http://a.com/service.asmx");
t.call(action, envelope);
```

This gives SSLProtocolException (but I don't want use SSL):

```
HttpsTransportSE t = new HttpsTransportSE("a.com", 80, "/service.asmx", timeout);
t.call(action, envelope);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpTransportSE(String url) should work.

Comment: HttpTransportSE(String url) is not in 2.5.4. At least not for me :)

Comment: That's strange, I am using 2.5.4 and HttpTransportSE is available. Have you imported the appropriate package (org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE)?

Answer (score 0):

The same question with `fhucho :HttpTransportSE(String url)`is not in 2.5.4,
there is `HttpTransportSE(host,port,filaname,timeout)`

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works for me, it should for you as well:

String webServiceResponse = null;
        SoapObject result = null;

```
    String url ="http://a.com/service.asmx";

    String soapaction = namespace + method;
    SoapObject request_login = new SoapObject(namespace, method);
    request.addProperty(<field_name>, <value>);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    try {
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(
                url);
        androidHttpTransport.call(soapaction, envelope);
        if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
            String str = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
            Log.i("", str);
            webServiceResponse = null;
        } else {
            result_login_String = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            webServiceResponse = result.getProperty(0)
                    .toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        webServiceResponse = null;
    }
```